# Is it safe to use "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" setting on the server and use session based cookies at the same time?

Tags: security, session, cookies, http-headers, express

I want to allow client applications to make cross domain JSON requests to a central data server. The clients and server will be on different domains.

To get around the "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin." error, I have the server set a:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

header.

I see here (http://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) that cross domain should only be used for "public data which doesn't require cookie or session based authentication".

Is is not safe to use session/cookie based authentication when using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header? If not why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a CORS ruleset of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` isn't a full Same-origin policy bypass, and is probably safe.

Having this header set on every page allows for [unauthenticated resource-requests](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests).  Authentication cookies are not implicitly included with these requests, so a cross-site XHR couldn't be used to lets say; read your email, or read CSRF tokens on a remote domain - because these requests would require a cookie or a bearer token.

Comment: How is this supposed to work when browsers won't allow access to resources that need credentials? The string "*" cannot be used for a resource that supports credentials. https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests. I realize this is an old answer, wasn't this the case in '11?

Comment: @bayotop you are correct, updated.  In my defense this was posted in 2011.